# Does every line in a Dockerfile create a new layer?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-layer

I understand the basic concepts of layers, Copy-on-Write (COW), and UnionFS, etc. I keep hearing that

> every line in a Dockerfile creates a new layer

So I did some experiments. Here is my Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM davidjfelix/python3.5

RUN mkdir -p /code/server
ADD app.py /code
ADD ./server /code/server
ADD requirements.txt /code/

WORKDIR /code
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

VOLUME /stuff

EXPOSE 7000

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "app.py"]
```

I've created a new image based on a Python 3.5 image. Upon inspecting both images using `docker inspect`, I observed that the new image has only **5** additional layers compared to the Python 3.5 image:

```json
"RootFS": {
    "Type": "layers",
    "Layers": [
        "sha256:6c3eb4525275f7040b8e3fbc846425ef934e1d44412d01cb37dc907d7d16e468",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
        "sha256:19f5e5ea72d6119ff25fb7bd45974cc108ae0bdc42bdeef1d805e1114502fe70",
        "sha256:cd55733e01aec60a4e2c644f5bbf14b4c543cc1bce38f1757e8dda457d19de28",
        "sha256:b8d8fe2d495aefca232e1a5b683b5ba3dce0661da29adc97e492274f31d9f4b6",
        "sha256:258951e4bcc601a96055b0bf6e230a298f27c44bd9838ab9fbe4fb4824f3f1ca",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
        "sha256:b421868bee11843b136d6051d5f497c6d47fa67d2d5895853c6055ef5c75ef5a",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef",
        "sha256:26f874482e486b9989aba19b50a9b8308cb29a8dc6d3d8da00d05373cb0bad1e",
        "sha256:4a3ef76df24253c3034313384494e3f8136c2580d2ddf423aaeed9297f83b22d",
        "sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The layers shown here are *filesystem* layers.
`Dockerfile` directives like `WORKDIR`, `VOLUME`, `EXPOSE`, `CMD` do not change the FS.

A [`docker history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/) would show those commands, but not [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).
See "[Show Layers of Docker Image](https://uberconf.com/blog/arun_gupta/2015/12/show_layers_of_docker_image)"